# Error in date and time parsing in Django ["'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 08:11:45 +0530' value has an invalid format. in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuu]][TZ] format."]

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am getting the rss feed as xml, and I am parsing , but date and time zone  is throwing an error

**My model field**

```
x = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**view.py**

```
y = MyModel()
y.x = prasedJson.pubdate
y.save()
```

**My xml date and time format from rss one of the feed**

```
   <pubDate>Tue, 02 Jul 2019 16:43:41 +0530</pubDate>
```

**Error is**

```
["'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 08:11:45 +0530' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

How can I save this date and time, either with +0530 or without +0530 format?

Comment: add your view.py code

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool i added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `parser` from [python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) library to parse date from string:

```
from dateutil import parser

parsed_date = parser.parse(prasedJson.pubdate)

y = MyModel()
y.x = parsed_date
y.save()
```